# Shoutcast Radio Streaming is Not working in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, shoutcast

I am using shoutcast streaming for android application It is working fine in all android versions below android 4.4. When I run the same application in Android 4.4.2 devices it is not working(not playing). I got the following message

> 04-03 04:46:39.175: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
>   04-03 04:46:39.175: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
>   04-03 04:46:39.175: W/AudioService(381): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples

Comment: Same problem here :-(